# jquery return to php

Tags: php, jquery

I try to send (from index.php) to test.php my id value , then to put the result of test.php echo to the same page php index.php  :

```
$('#MY_ID').click(function()
  {
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax(
         {
          type: 'POST',
          url: "test.php",
          data:  {name:name},
          success:function(result)
           {
             alert(result),
              $.ajax(
                     {
                      type:'POST',
                      url: "index.php",
                       data:  {test_value:result},

                      });

            }
           })
      });
```

so when I use in php file :

```
<?php if (isset ($_POST['test_value'])){echo $_POST['test_value'];}
      else echo 'rusu';?>
```

to echo the result from test.php but do not work

Comment: Have you check firebug? Especially in `net` tab.

Comment: Add `success:function(result)
           { }` after `data:  {test_value:result},`

Comment: I try...but no result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP almost certainly is echoing the correct value (and since you are outputting user input directly as HTML, that renders you vulnerable to XSS attacks).

You can't see the result because you haven't got a `success` handler for your second call to `$.ajax`.

Using Ajax to make an HTTP request to the URL of the current page will get you a new HTTP response with data in it that is available to JavaScript. It won't retroactively overwrite any existing rendering that the browser might be doing of the same URL.

If you want to do anything with that data, you have to write JavaScript to take it and modify the DOM with it.

Comment: Regarding XSS vulnerability... does it really? Because the way I see it all a user can do is hax their own browser.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol — All it needs is a form on the attackers with with the `action` set the absolute URI for `index.php` and some JavaScript to call `thatForm.submit()`. The data comes from the third party, it gets sent to the site, the site sends it back as HTML (which can have embedded JavaScript), the browser trusts it as any other data from the site.

Comment: Aah, I see. I gotcha. I don't do this kind of thing anyway (not without sanitisation) so I'm not too worried, but thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

You have no `success` callback defined in your `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: { 'name': name},
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result),
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: {'test_value': result},
            success: function(response) {
                // Handle response here.
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I try...but no result :(

Comment: How are you handling `response`?

Comment: i just use success:function(result) { };

Comment: As indicated, you need to do something with the `result` element.

Comment: if i use alert(response) it will return the entire page

Comment: OK, and what do you want to do with that page (instead of alerting it)?

Comment: so when I use in php file :

<?php if (isset ($_POST['test_value'])){echo $_POST['test_value'];}
      else echo 'rusu';?>
to echo the result from test.php but do not work